# Android studio 3 profiler. How to identify cause for objects stuck in the heap

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to understand how to identify and solve memory leaks.
I know how to deal with general memory leak issues. Leaked activities, inner classes etc. They are usually quite easy to identify. By dumping the heap and look for references.

Right now i am stuck with something probably very simple. Some very small object are stuck in the heap and i just cannot find any references to it in the heap explorer. See image below.

[image]

As you can see there is a MatchOddsAdapterStickyHeader instance and an array containing these instances. 
My question is why these objects are still in the heap.?
The MatchOddsAdapterStickyHeader[] instance only contains references to a single MatchOddsAdapterStickyHeader instance. And each single MatchOddsAdapterStickyHeader only have a string. I just don't understand why GC did not clean up this objects. Both object have no references to any alive object. And yes i forced GC. makes no difference.

I know its only a few bytes. And it doesn't really give a problem in my app, but still i want to have a 100% memory leak free app if possible.

Comment: Share your code what is BOOKMAKER in your code ?